# How create settings but global redirect?

Tags: php, redirect

I need to, when a person comes to mysite.com/index.html -> refirect to mysite.com/index.php or

mysite.com/index.phtml -> mysite.com/index.php. or
mysite.com/index.sdsf -> mysite.com/index.php. or

mysite.com/about.phtml -> mysite.com/about.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to catch incorrect filenames, then that's something you have to do outside of PHP. Try a mod_rewrite rule like:

```
 RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
 RewriteRule  ^index\.(?!php)\w+$  index.php [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all incoming requests to direct to `/index.php` using PHP?

You could try...

```
if ( ! preg_match('/\/^index\.php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
   location('Header: /index.php');
   exit;
}
```

**Note**, you should use the full URL in the redirect.

Otherwise, if you wanted to select those ones you mention exclusively, you could build an array of them, and then loop and check.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to redirect it? Why not just use index.php as your default page?

Anyway, a good way to do this would be by use of `header`

```
header('Location: http://mysite.com/index.php');
```

Hope that helps.